# Using theme options in header.php

Tags: wordpress

Im presently working on a theme where I would like to user to be able to change the logo image.
Im using the NHP Theme framework.
But for some reason

```
<?php
echo $options['logo'];
?>
```

does nothing in the header.php. It works in index.php but not header.php...
How can I make it echo in the header as well?

Answer (score 0):

It's pure guess. But in lot of frameworks the close tag ?> can cause a problem. Try just

```
<?php
echo $options['logo'];
```

without the close tag, if you have pure php file.

Comment: But I have html after that so I don't think that's such a good idea